# Export of all threads (with comments) of a group to a text programm (Word or Indesign)

Tags: facebook, export-to-excel

Single threads can be exported with drag and drop, but in some groups are in several threads are up to 700 comments, impossible for drag and drop.
Planned were export of all threads and Comments for a one better two years...
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the free export tool from rorohiko ?
http://www.rorohiko.com/wordpress/indesign-downloads/text-exporter/

Loic
http://www.loicaigon.com